# Swift Playgrounds: Floats always rounded when displayed in the built-in variable viewer

Tags: swift, precision, swift-playground

Using Swift Playgrounds I am experimenting with some maths problems, specifically using the pow function.  If I were to do the following:

```
var x: Float = powf(0.2, 2)
```

It returns 0.04 as the answer as expected.

However, if I change this so that the base is 0.02 (or less), then the result is 0.0 in the viewer. I wanted to avoid using Decimal as this is to later go into Apple's Accelerate framework.

How do I retain the correct value of this?

Comment: What you see is not what you get, do `print(x)`

Comment: That's odd, are you sure you're not performing any additional operation to that var? Playground doesn't that rounding by itself...

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `powf(0.02, 2)` displays as `0.0004` in the Playground.

Comment: Your latest edit increases the confusion: `powf(0.2, 2)`  is 0.04, it cannot return 0.0004.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is reproducible in Swift Playground 2.2 on iPad.

The value is calculated correctly, but the built in viewer for type Float seems to only display two decimal digits by default. As far as I know, there is no documented way to change this.

However, you can build a string out of your variable either by calling `print(x)` or by manually creating one using `String(format: "%f", x)`.

Attached screenshot illustrates the behavior of the built in variable viewer.
[image]

Comment: Note that OP is under the impression that the actual float value gets truncated and that another data type is needed.